# Rufus-scheduler blocks main thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I have a Rails project that needs to scrape the web every x hours. For that, I am using rufus-scheduler. When the job is running, however, the API slows way down, from under 1000ms to 30s or more. Checking the logs, Activerecord is not the cause of the extra latency. I can see that the passenger thread is using 100% of my CPU.

In another Rails project, I'm running an external script (`youtube-dl`) from rufus scheduler. When the script is running, the API blocks entirely sometimes (but other times is unphased).

In both cases, I am using Rails 6, Ruby 2.6.4, and Debian 9. I was thinking of installing sidekiq and having Rufus call it, so that my scheduled jobs would run in a separate process. Is there something I should be doing instead?

Comment: It's not really rufus-scheduler blocking your main thread, it's the code it calls that does. So yes, offloading the work to another process (even another machine) is the way to go.

Comment: @jmettraux Thanks. Is calling Sidekiq from Rufus bad practice? If not, that is what I will do.

Comment: it's not bad practice at all, there are at least two projects who leverage both out there: https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler and https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron